# How to specify squaring the difference of two unsigned numbers in Chisel3?

Tags: chisel

Here is one way do it that seems ugly.

```scala
class DiffSquared extends Module {
  val inputWidth = 8
  val width = 16
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val X = Input(UInt(inputWidth.W))
    val M = Input(UInt(inputWidth.W))
    val Out = Output(UInt(width.W))
  })
  val x = Wire(UInt((inputWidth+1).W))
  val m = Wire(UInt((inputWidth+1).W))
  x := io.X
  m := io.M
  val diff = Wire(SInt((inputWidth+1).W))
  diff := x.asSInt - m.asSInt
  io.Out := (diff*diff).asUInt
}
```

What is a better way to zero-extend the UInt to a 9 bit SInt, do the difference, square it, and represent the result as a 16 bit UInt?

Answer (score 1):

Since no one bit, here is a slight improvement.
Should we add a zero extension method to UInt to make this better?
Is there already one there?

```
class DiffSquared extends Module {
  val inputWidth = 8
  val width = 16
  val io = IO( new Bundle{
    val X = Input(UInt(inputWidth.W))
    val M = Input(UInt(inputWidth.W))
    val Out = Output(UInt(width.W))
  })
  def zX(w:UInt) = Wire(UInt((w.getWidth+1).W),init=w).asSInt
  val diff = Wire(init=zX(io.X)-zX(io.M))
  io.Out := (diff*diff).asUInt
}
```

Comment: A general sign extension method could be useful. Feel free to file a feature request!

Answer (score 1):

There's a useful function here: [zext](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/api/index.html#chisel3.core.UInt@zext():chisel3.core.SInt) that zero extends a UInt to an SInt of the UInt's width + 1. Thus you could write the code as:

```scala
class DiffSquared extends Module {
  val inputWidth = 8
  val width = 16
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val X = Input(UInt(inputWidth.W))
    val M = Input(UInt(inputWidth.W))
    val Out = Output(UInt(width.W))
  })
  val diff = io.X.zext() - io.M.zext()
  io.Out := (diff*diff).asUInt
}
```